# Incidents where airline pilots recovered effectively from errors

Tags: accident-investigation, airline-pilot, incidents

I am training airline instructors in competency-based assessment and grading skills, and could use examples of pilot resilience where there are both good and not-so-good competencies in play.
To this end, I am looking for examples of incidents where airline pilots made errors while managing a threat, but recovered effectively and brought the situation to a safe conclusion.
As an example, a poor decision to continue to destination despite poor weather,  effectively managed by an early go-around and diversion,
Another example might be a malfunction that was initially misunderstood and mismanaged, but later correctly recognised and dealt with.
Investigation reports, videos etc would be very helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's an entire database of crew reported incidents called the Aviation Safety Reporting System. It is a confidential, voluntary, and non-punitive system. ASRS captures confidential reports, analyzes the resulting aviation safety data, and disseminates vital information to the aviation community.

The FAA encourages crew members to report incidents so that the community can learn from them.

You can search it at [ASRS](https://asrs.arc.nasa.gov/search/database.html).

Comment: Thanks for this.  I know about ASRs (have filed a few over the years!) but was unaware of this comprehensive database.  What a great learning resource.